# json convert array for ajax post

Tags: json

Do anybody by any chance know how i go from:

```
var guests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(apartments) ; i++) {
     var pos = i + 1;

     var adults, children, infants;

     adults = $("#adults" + pos).val();
     infants = $("#infants" + pos).val();
     children = $("#children" + pos).val();
     guests.push({ Leg: pos, Adults: adults,
        Children: children, Infants: infants 
     });
}
```

To something this:

```
Guests: [{ Leg: "1", Adults: "2", Children: "0", Infants: "2" },{ Leg:
"2", Adults: "2", Children: "1", Infants: "0" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
JSON.stringify(guests);
```

I think that should do it.